# Use route prefix with RESTful routes in CakePHP

Tags: rest, cakephp, routes, prefix

Working on building an API and would like to use [RESTful routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html#rest).

I got it to work just fine like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/events.json  // returns json results with my events
http://www.mysite.com/events/123.json // returns json results with event of id '123'
```

BUT - I want to be able to do this using an 'api' prefix.

So, I added the api Routing prefix:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'api'));
```

And changed my actions from 'view' and 'index' to 'api_view' and 'api_index'.

But now it doesn't work. (eg. I have to write the action name or it won't find the correct one based on HTTP.

The end goal would be to be able to do something like this:

```
GET http://www.mysite.com/api/1.0/events.json // loads events/api_index()
GET http://www.mysite.com/api/1.0/events/123.json // loads events/api_view($id)
DELETE http://www.mysite.com/api/1.0/events/123.json // loads events/api_delete($id)
...etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up having to just write the routes manually:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml');

Router::connect('/api/:version/:controller/:id/*',
array('[method]'=>'GET', 'prefix'=>'api', 'action'=>'view'),
array('version'=>'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', 'id'=>'[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}'));

Router::connect('/api/:version/:controller/*',
array('[method]'=>'GET', 'prefix'=>'api', 'action'=>'index'),
array('version'=>'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'));

Router::connect('/api/*', array('controller'=>'events', 'action'=>'index', 'ext'=>'html'));
```

---

**Notes:**

The `[method]` is what forces the HTTP type (eg. RESTful)

The `parseExtensions()` makes it so you can have it display the data in different formats automatically by changing the extension in your URL.

The last Router:: line was just a catchall for anything /api/ that didn't match - it forwarded it to the homepage.  Eventually I'll probably just route this to an API error page.

The `'ext'=>'html'` of the last Router:: line was to keep parseExtensions from trying to use whatever extension was in the URL - if it's redirecting for reasons they made the call wrong, I just want it to go back to the homepage (or whatever) and use the normal view.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
Router::connect('/:api/:apiVersion/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array(
        'api' => 'api',
        'apiVersion' => '1.0|1.1|'
    )
);
```

With prefix routing

```
Router::connect('/:prefix/:apiVersion/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array(
        'prefix' => 'api',
        'apiVersion' => '1.0|1.1|'
    )
);
```

Will match only valid API versions like 1.0 and 1.1 here. If you want something else use a regex there.

Comment: I can manage the router just fine - the issue is then also allowing REST to determine whether it should display 'view' or 'index'...etc based on HTTP type.

Comment: The declare the routes and use [method] in the 2nd argument array. Like shown here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#using-additional-conditions-when-matching-routes See also https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin

Comment: I think I get it - will try in the morning.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Hitting `http://wwwmydomain.com/api/1.0/events/12345.json` gives "Action EventsController::api_12345() could not be found." - it should be looking for `api_view()`.

Comment: It is obvious that you need a second route that comes after the route in my answer that will be a catch all like /:prefix/:apiVersion/:controller/*

Comment: I've tried that too - but the point of the question is not "how to get routes to work" - it's how to be able to use a prefix and still retain the functionality of mapResources (ie automatically determine the view based on the HTTP type)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but there is a routing method called mapResources which creates the special method based routing for you.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

You put it in routes.php like so:

```
Router::mapResources(array('controller1', 'controller2'));
```

The docs have a nice little table showing how the requests are mapped to different actions, which you can always override if you need to.